# Android BluetoothAdapter.CancelDiscovery doesn't cancel discovery

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have the discovery status hooked up to a broadcast receiver. I can start a scan and let it stop after the default timeout of 12 seconds, and I'll get both the DiscoveryStarted and DiscoveryFinished actions. Running this code

```
_bluetoothAdapter.CancelDiscovery();
```

does not do anything. 12 seconds later, I get the DiscoveryFinished action after it times out. How can you force this thing to stop scanning? It is really slowing down my bluetooth connection process.

Here is my broadcast receiver subscription:

```
filter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound);
filter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionBondStateChanged);
filter.AddAction(BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryStarted);
filter.AddAction(BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished);
context.RegisterReceiver(_bluetoothDeviceReceiver, filter);
```

and handler:

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        string action = intent.Action;

        if (action == BluetoothDevice.ActionFound)
        {
            BluetoothDevice newDevice = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref DeviceFound, null, null)?.Invoke(newDevice);
        }

        if (action == BluetoothDevice.ActionBondStateChanged)
        {
            BluetoothDevice newDevice = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
            if (newDevice.BondState == Bond.Bonded)
            {
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref BondComplete, null, null)?.Invoke(newDevice);
            }
        }

        if (action == BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnected || action == BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnectRequested)
        {
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref Disconnected, null, null)?.Invoke();
        }

        if (action == BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryStarted)
        {
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref ScanningStateChanged, null, null)?.Invoke(true);
        }


        if (action == BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished)
        {
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref ScanningStateChanged, null, null)?.Invoke(false);
        }
    }
```